# Link UITableView delegate function back to other function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a custom alert method, with a UITableView inside it.

```
typedef void (^Succes)(id data);
typedef void (^Failure)(NSError *error);

+ (void)testForTable:(NSString *)title withSuccess:(Succes)success failure:(Failure)failure {
    SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] initWithNewWindow];
    alert.customViewColor = [UIColor paperColorLightBlue500];
    [alert setShowAnimationType:SlideInFromRight];
    UITableView *tableView = [alert addTableView];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [alert showEdit:self title:@"Test for table"
                subTitle:@"This is a test alert for a table"
        closeButtonTitle:nil duration:0.0f];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Methods
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 40;

}

+ (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

+ (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

+ (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
}
```

Now, ideally, when a user touches a `UITableViewCell`, I'd like `indexPath.row` to be passed back to the `Success` parameter of `testForTable`. How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

SCLAlertView should  be the delegate of the UITableView, so it can handle the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Seeing as the dataSource is very simple, SCLAlertView could also be the dataSource.

So:

```
tableView.delegate = alert;
tableView.dataSource = alert;
```

then move your delegate implementation into the SCLAlertView.

*Edit*

I don't know what kind of object `Success` is, but if it's a block, you could keep a reference of it on the `UIViewController` and call it when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` too.

*Edit 2*

your success block would need to accept an NSInteger parameter:

```
typedef void (^Success)(id data, NSInteger row);
```

and then you would call it on the delegate:

```
+ (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id data; //this data is a placeholder, i dont know how you get this.
    if (self.success) {
        self.success(data, indexPath.row);
    }
}
```

you could hold a reference of the success block on the delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) Success success;
```

Comment: I've added `Success` and `Failure` to the question. If I follow your solution and move the delegate to SCLAlertView; how would I pass the selected row back then? How do I register a row selection?